# PyAutoGUI doesn't move cursor or click inside a virtual machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtual-machine, pyautogui

I searched around, but haven't found a working solution.
I can't make PyAutoGUI move the cursor or click inside the virtual machine. I'm using virt-manager, python3, and running the script from inside the virtual machine.
A simple code like `pyautogui.moveTo(600, 340, 1)` does nothing. no errors or anything, it simply does nothing and finishes script execution 'succesfully'.

i suspect it is trying to use the host mouse and keyboard, which of course is not possible. is there some way to emulate the virtual cursor or something like that?

thanks in advance!

I searched, but haven't found any config from virt-manager that could fix that.
i expect the code to move the virtual machine cursor, and leave the host cursor to be used by me on the host machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is related to this, but I simply installed in the GUEST, the package spice-vdagent (i'm using spice as the 'interface'). Then I upgraded both the host and guest. After upgrading I restarted everything. These pyautogui scripts are working now, and I can  also copy/paste text and files between the host and guest.

It works minimized and everything.